# Connecting html page to jupyter python notebook

Tags: javascript, html, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have a nearest neighbor algorithm setup on an jupyter ipython notebook and want to be able to make queries to that notebook from an html/javascript page and then return the results to the web page for display. Does anyone have any idea how to proceed.
I've seen several tutorials regarding embedding html in a notebook but nothing on linking the two. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you find the solution?